# Prevent django widthratio calculating more than 100 %

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-templates

Im trying to put together a bootstrap 3 progress bar with multiple percentage values ([see docs example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-stacked)).

The combined value of all the values can not be more than 100%, but django is rounding up, and I'm getting a value of 101%

```
#max_width = 100
#total.count = 17

#a.count = 11 (65%)
#b.count = 2 (12%)
#c.count = 4 (24%)


<div class="progress">   
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: {% widthratio a.count total.count max_width %}%">
    {{ a.count }} ({% widthratio a.count total.count max_width %}%)
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: {% widthratio b.count total.count max_width %}%">
    {{ b.count }} ({% widthratio b.count total.count max_width %}%)
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: {% widthratio c.count total.count max_width %}%">
    {{ c.count }} ({% widthratio c.count total.count max_width %}%)
  </div>

</div>
```

Output

```
<div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 65%">
        11 (65%)
      </div>
      <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 12%">
        2 (12%)
      </div>
      <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 24%">
        4 (24%)
      </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, all the percentage is added up to 101%, and therefore the last value is not displaying in the progress bar. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this, which doesn't really help. I am looking at the same issue.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12026

Not sure if this is the best approach but:

```
@register.simple_tag
def percentage(value, total):
    return float(value)/float(total) * 100
```

and then in the template:
style="width: {% percentage group.count total.count %}%;"